# Installing cvxpy on windows with anaconda: failed nosetests misrebally

Tags: installation, nose, cvxpy

Please explain what I should do slowly. I am trying to install cvxpy on my machine. I have installed python, visual studio build tools and tried in command prompt but I got errors when I tried to install. So I ditched that idea and installed anaconda and I am now able to install and but fail nosestests.

```
(base) C:\Users\Ahmed>pip install --upgrade setuptools
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/72/1c1498c1e908e0562b1e1cd30012580baa7d33b5b0ffdbeb5fde2462cc71/setuptools-45.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 41.4.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-41.4.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-41.4.0
Successfully installed setuptools-45.2.0

(base) C:\Users\Ahmed>pip uninstall cvxpy
Uninstalling cvxpy-1.0.28:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_cvxcore.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
    c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy-1.0.28.dist-info\*
    c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\*
    c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\examples\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled cvxpy-1.0.28
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2007 tests in 63.686s

FAILED (SKIP=3, errors=14, failures=2)
```

Update: I was not able to include entire log because it was too long and was flagged as spam. The context is this: I don't remember much about programming but I learned it at one time. I am trying to install cvxpy to use the geometric programming feature. I use the instructions on cvxpy.org for installation on windows shows below:

[windows install instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGrq3.png)

and got the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed>pip install cvxpy
Collecting cvxpy
  Using cached cvxpy-1.0.28.tar.gz (947 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting scs>=1.1.3
  Using cached scs-2.1.1-2.tar.gz (157 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ahmed\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bg44_ccb\\scs\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ahmed\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bg44_ccb\\scs\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bg44_ccb\scs\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bg44_ccb\scs\
    Complete output (100 lines):
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\tools\cythonize.py", line 61, in process_pyx
        from Cython.Compiler.Version import version as cython_version
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\tools\cythonize.py", line 238, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\tools\cythonize.py", line 234, in main
        find_process_files(root_dir)
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\tools\cythonize.py", line 225, in find_process_files
        process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\tools\cythonize.py", line 191, in process
        processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\tools\cythonize.py", line 66, in process_pyx
        raise OSError('Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module')
    OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\setup.py", line 488, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\setup.py", line 469, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\setup.py", line 275, in generate_cython
    RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bg44_ccb\scs\setup.py", line 229, in <module>
        run_install()
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bg44_ccb\scs\setup.py", line 226, in run_install
        install_scs()
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bg44_ccb\scs\setup.py", line 201, in install_scs
        setup(
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "c:\users\ahmed\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\setup.py", line 488, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\setup.py", line 469, in setup_package
      File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-uiqw24ti\numpy-1.18.1\setup.py", line 275, in generate_cython
    RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
    Namespace(blas64=False, extraverbose=False, float32=False, gpu=False, int32=False, scs=False)
    Cythonizing sources
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Then I decided to use Anaconda which I had to install and then used the following instrcutions:

[Anaconda installation guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5vg9.png)

No errors from pip installation. The following errors from anaconda prompt:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed>pip install cvxpy
Requirement already satisfied: cvxpy in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.28)
Requirement already satisfied: ecos>=2 in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy) (2.0.7.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: scs>=1.1.3 in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy) (2.1.1.post2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1.0 in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: multiprocess in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy) (0.70.9)
Requirement already satisfied: osqp>=0.4.1 in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dill>=0.3.1 in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from multiprocess->cvxpy) (0.3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\ahmed\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from osqp>=0.4.1->cvxpy) (0.17.1)
```

nosetests errors are below:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Test eigenvalue atoms.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test log det.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test matrix_frac atom.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        SCS v2.1.1 - Splitting Conic Solver
        (c) Brendan O'Donoghue, Stanford University, 2012
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lin-sys: sparse-direct, nnz in A = 65
eps = 1.00e-06, alpha = 1.50, max_iters = 7500, normalize = 1, scale = 1.00
acceleration_lookback = 0, rho_x = 1.00e-03
Variables n = 26, constraints m = 46
Cones:  primal zero / dual free vars: 31
        sd vars: 15, sd blks: 1
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Setup time: 2.11e-04s
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test matrix norms.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\tests\test_complex.py", line 304, in test_matrix_norms
    result = prob.solve()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 290, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 575, in _solve
    self.unpack_results(solution, full_chain, inverse_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 718, in unpack_results
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test Hermitian variables.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test with special index.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: test_gen_lambda_max_matrix_completion (cvxpy.tests.test_dqcp.TestDqcp)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\tests\test_dqcp.py", line 466, in test_gen_lambda_max_matrix_completion
    problem.solve(cp.SCS, qcp=True)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 290, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 558, in _solve
    chain.reduce(), solver=solver, verbose=verbose, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\reductions\solvers\bisection.py", line 167, in bisect
    _solve(lowered_feas, solver)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\reductions\solvers\bisection.py", line 36, in _solve
    problem.solve(solver=solver)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 290, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 575, in _solve
    self.unpack_results(solution, full_chain, inverse_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 718, in unpack_results
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
WARN: m less than n, problem likely degenerate
WARN: A->p (column pointers) not strictly increasing, column 7 empty
WARN: A->p (column pointers) not strictly increasing, column 8 empty
WARN: A->p (column pointers) not strictly increasing, column 9 empty
WARN: A->p (column pointers) not strictly increasing, column 11 empty
WARN: A->p (column pointers) not strictly increasing, column 13 empty
WARN: A->p (column pointers) not strictly increasing, column 14 empty
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: test_log_det (cvxpy.tests.test_examples.TestExamples)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test a problem with diag.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\tests\test_problem.py", line 1430, in test_diag_prob
    result = prob.solve()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 290, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 575, in _solve
    self.unpack_results(solution, full_chain, inverse_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 718, in unpack_results
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test positive definite constraints.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test complex matrices.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test sdp var.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        SCS v2.1.1 - Splitting Conic Solver
        (c) Brendan O'Donoghue, Stanford University, 2012
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lin-sys: sparse-direct, nnz in A = 15
eps = 1.00e-04, alpha = 1.50, max_iters = 5000, normalize = 1, scale = 1.00
acceleration_lookback = 0, rho_x = 1.00e-03
Variables n = 6, constraints m = 15
Cones:  primal zero / dual free vars: 9
        sd vars: 6, sd blks: 1
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Setup time: 3.62e-04s
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test sigma_max.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Traceback left out
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
ERROR: Test that results are symmetric.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\tests\test_semidefinite_vars.py", line 43, in test_symm
    prob.solve()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 290, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 575, in _solve
    self.unpack_results(solution, full_chain, inverse_data)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 718, in unpack_results
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'SCS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
FATAL: Cannot solve SDPs with > 2x2 matrices without linked blas+lapack libraries
Install blas+lapack and re-compile SCS with blas+lapack libray locations
ERROR: init_cone failure
Failure:could not initialize work

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
FAIL: Test silencing and enabling solver messages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\tests\test_problem.py", line 281, in test_verbose
    assert len(output) == 0
AssertionError:
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
ECOS
ECOS_BB
OSQP
SCS
ECOS
ECOS_BB
OSQP
SCS

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

======================================================================
FAIL: test_sdp_problem (cvxpy.tests.test_semidefinite_vars.TestSemidefiniteVariable)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\tests\test_semidefinite_vars.py", line 51, in test_sdp_problem
    self.assertAlmostEqual(result, 1, places=4)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\tests\base_test.py", line 38, in assertAlmostEqual
    super(BaseTest, self).assertAlmostEqual(a, b, places=places)
AssertionError: 0.999896846515758 != 1 within 4 places (0.00010315348424194681 difference)
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
WARN: aa_init returned NULL, no acceleration applied.

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2007 tests in 72.683s

FAILED (SKIP=3, errors=14, failures=2)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more context. Can you include the specific error messages output by nosetests? The entire log would be helpful. Same for the errors you saw from the pip installation.

Comment: I have updated the post. I hope this is more clear and complete.

Comment: It looks like your SCS installation is broken. I would recommend creating a fresh environment, and then installing numpy, scs, and cvxpy, in that order.

Comment: So I uninstall and deleted the directory for anaconda and uninstalled python 3.8. I then installed python 3.8 and then installed anadonda3 (python 3.7). I then ran pip install (numpy, scs, cvxpy, nose) and then ran nosetests cvxpy. I am getting the same thing: FAILED (SKIP=3, errors=14, failures=2). Is there something wrong with what I am doing. Also is this what you meant by fresh environment.

Comment: I think the issue is being addressed in the link below. [link](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/492) Although, I am not entirely sure what was the solution.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have posted my answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to install cvxpy successfully. I found this [github issue](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/492) very helpful. I ended up install Python 3.8 (64-bit) instead of (32-bit) which I had by accident. I installed

> (numpy+mkl, scipy, cvxopt, scs, ecos, and osqp) in that order and all from downloaded wheels except for scs which I did using pip install scs I then did pip install nose and then nosetests cvxpy and go the following output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

The pre-compiled wheels can be found [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Just download each one and move it to your working directory and then run `pip install filename.whl`